# how do i add a partition key using Azure.ResourceManager.CosmosDB c#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-rm-template

I can create a database and container without an issue on both gremlin and sql, ut I can't seem to set the partition key.

I would expect to do

///
var containerParams = new SqlContainerCreateUpdateParameters
(
new SqlContainerResource(databaseName)
{

```
                    PartitionKey = new ContainerPartitionKey()
                    {
                        Paths = new List<string>{partialKey}
                    }
                },
                new CreateUpdateOptions()
            )
```

///

I would expect to do something like this, but the Paths field is readonly, and I can't see any other option to set it.

[Update]
i got it working with creating an object then converting to json and back to ContainerPartitionKey

Comment: Can you explain what operation are you trying to perform? The PartitionKey is normally needed when performing Data Plane operations, for which you need Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos

Comment: I am assigning partition keys to help with defining search to smaller record sets and to maintain partition sizes to allow for database growth, however you can't use User Identities Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos,it returns a 403 error no matter the role I assign, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/tutorial-vm-managed-identities-cosmos?tabs=azure-portal

Answer (score 0):

Here is the syntax for creating the partition key using Cosmos DB Azure Management SDK.

```
SqlContainerCreateUpdateParameters sqlContainerCreateUpdateParameters = new SqlContainerCreateUpdateParameters
{
    Resource = new SqlContainerResource
    {
        Id = containerName,
        DefaultTtl = -1, //-1 = off, 0 = on no default, >0 = ttl in seconds
        AnalyticalStorageTtl = -1,
        PartitionKey = new ContainerPartitionKey
        {
        Kind = "Hash",
        Paths = new List<string> { "/myPartitionKey" },
        Version = 1 //version 2 for large partition key
    }
}
```

You can find a complete SqlContainer create example [here](https://github.com/markjbrown/cosmos-management-net/blob/master/cosmos-management-generated/Sql.cs#L123). You can also find a complete set of examples for how to use the [Azure Management SDK for Cosmos DB](https://github.com/markjbrown/cosmos-management-net) in GitHub. Please note, it is out of date but should still work for illustrating how to use to manage Cosmos resources.

Comment: That is using Microsoft.Azure.Management.CosmosDB, and I am using Azure.ResourceManager.CosmosDB as it supports DefaultAzureCredential and user identities, Azure.ResourceManager.CosmosDB is the recommended package for RBAC https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/tutorial-vm-managed-identities-cosmos?tabs=azure-portal

Comment: Same thing. Both Azure Management libraries are auto-generated from the same underlying Cosmos DB REST API swagger spec. The only exception is the authentication via `Azure.Identity` versus `Microsoft.Rest.Azure.Authentication`. The samples I provided should just work.

Comment: all the MS docs say use DefaultAzureCredentials, which is great because I can use active directory for local build and testing and User Assigned Identities throughout on azure without any coding changes, the example you can't use a User Identity, the models from both libraries are almost the same but the getters and setters are different which is typical Azure